# In my project it failed to add "firebase" to android studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I was adding firebase to my project as documented in the official website.

In the 4th step it says to add `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'`.

But trying to synch gradle I would get errors:

[image]

and by trying to download them (`install repository abd synch project`) I would get this error:

[image]

here is my gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.6.5'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

this answer did not work either:
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39137252/9850245)

***update***

My project-level gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}
```

Comment: again read plz https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?authuser=0

Comment: Not an answer but use `implementation` instead of `compile`.

Comment: Have you added `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the end of your build.gradle file? I cannot see it in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade the following:

```
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.2'
```

into this:

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
```

Add  google service plugin version `4.0.1` and `google()` repo in top level gradle file:

```
buildscript {
// ...
dependencies {
    // ...
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' // google-services plugin
  }
}

allprojects {
// ...
repositories {
    // ...
    google() // Google's Maven repository
    }
 }
```

Comment: I had them all, see my post update. I changed 11.6.2 to 16.0.2 but the same errors again.

Answer (score 0):

Use same versions of firebase services to avoid conflicts.
Refer https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup
To solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Before you proceed, clean and rebuild your project.

Then at **app/build.gradle**,

add **`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`** 
like the code snippet down below.

```
android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And make sure all the library used are as [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).

Hope it helps!

Comment: I cannot clean project:Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:11.6.2.

Comment: @hsbr13 did you apply the plugin? Can update your code at the question?

Comment: @hsbr13 see properly,at app/build.gradle, add the apply plugin to the bottom after dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Add `firebase-core` to your dependencies block:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

The [Firebase SDK release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) for the June 12 release explain:

> Your app gradle file now has to explicitly list
>   com.google.firebase:firebase-core as a dependency for Firebase
>   services to work as expected.

It's also safer to list `google()` first in repository lists:

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    ...
}
```

Comment: Did you also change `firebase-auth:11.6.2` to use a new version, e.g. `16.0.2`?